# School's tuition insurance charge eligible for 529 reimbursement?

Tags: united-states, insurance, 529-plan, tuition

My son's tuition bill includes around $100 for tuition insurance. Can I have this paid directly from the 529 account to the university, or must I pay that separately?

[Articles I've read](https://thecollegeinvestor.com/18450/qualified-expenses-529-plan/#tab-con-4) researching this discuss health insurance as not being reimbursable, but I found no discussion of tuition insurance charged by the university. Is it considered a fee charged by the school?

Thanks!

Comment: If it's on the bursar's bill, we pay it from 529 funds.  If the IRS ever audits me and says I was wrong, I'll plead honest ignorance: "it's on the tuition bill!!!"